# How to execute SQL view

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I have a view called 'selectView' in my postgresql database.

How i can get the results in to my server.js(nodejs code) like,

`select * from selectView`

Please suggest.

Comment: There is no difference in selecting from a view or from a table. If your library can display the results of a `select * from some_table` it can also display the results of `select * from selectView`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had made some mistakes in nodejs code that causes some issues in getting view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the earlier mis-understanding. Didn't know node.js was server-side. A little search engine (you know the one) tells me that there's a postgresql library available for node.js. That should help you out.

Look here: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres

Comment: Yes.i am using this pg module only in node. It executes only the query not views in postgres db. I am new to view concept also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had made some mistakes in nodejs code that causes some issues in getting view.